# Counting how many unique identifiers there are by merging two columns of data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, defaultdict

I'm trying to make a really simple counting script I guess using defaultdict (I can't get my head around how to use DefaultDict so if someone could comment me a snippit of code I would greatly appreciate it)

My objective is to take element 0 and element 1, merge them into a single string and then to count how many unique strings there are...

For example, in the below data there are 15 lines consisting of 3 classes, 4 classids which when merged together we only have 3 unique classes. The merged data for the first line (ignoring the title row) is: `Class01CD2`

#### CSV Data:

```
uniq1,uniq2,three,four,five,six
Class01,CD2,data,data,data,data
Class01,CD2,data,data,data,data
Class01,CD2,data,data,data,data
Class01,CD2,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,data,data
DClass2,DE2,data,data,data,data
DClass2,DE2,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD1,data,data,data,data
Class02,CD1,data,data,data,data
```

The idea of it is to simply print out how many unique classes are available.
Anyone able to help me work this out?

Regards
- Hyflex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since you are dealing with CSV data, you can use the CSV module along with dictionaries:**

```
import csv

uniq = {} #Create an empty dictionary, which we will use as a hashmap as Python dictionaries support key-value pairs.

ifile = open('data.csv', 'r') #whatever your CSV file is named.
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

for row in reader:
    joined = row[0] + row[1] #The joined string is simply the first and second columns in each row.
    #Check to see that the key exists, if it does increment the occurrence by 1
    if joined in uniq.keys():
        uniq[joined] += 1
    else:
        uniq[joined] = 1 #This means the key doesn't exist, so add the key to the dictionary with an occurrence of 1

print uniq #Now output the results
```

This outputs:

```
{'Class02CD3': 7, 'Class02CD1': 2, 'Class01CD2': 3, 'DClass2DE2': 2}
```

NOTE: This is assuming that the CSV doesn't have the header row (`uniq1,uniq2,three,four,five,six`).

REFERENCES:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: @Hyflex: Thanks for the edit. I didn't catch that I had mistyped until you had suggested it.

Comment: Whilst what you coded will definitely come in handy, it's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. The output should be just a simple 3 (as their are 3 unique classes. That however is easy to do after what you coded with a simple: `print len(uniq)`

Comment: @PatrickKostjens any reason for changing it from ifile to file?

Comment: @Hyflex, sorry my bad, I misread the message while reviewing the edit.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens: Note: `file` is the name of a builtin Python function.

Comment: @jrd1 code works beautifully, I did add enumerate in it so I could skip the first line (titles are in my original csv files). Thank you ever so much :)

Comment: @Hyflex: No problem. Glad I could be of service. And, thank you as well! :)

Comment: There is no reason to use a `dict` here (nor a `defaultdict` as OP had in mind). We're not trying to count the appearances of each key or anything else (and if we were, `collections.Counter` would be a more appropriate tool!), so all we need is a `set`. That lets us write the code much more simply.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that joining the strings isn't necessarily the cleanest representation of what's intended. Making a `tuple` of the two strings would be fine (those can be stored in a `set`) and more clearly represents the idea of "key composed of the two column values". With string concatenation, a column 1 value of "fo" with a column 2 value of "obar" would be treated the same as a column 1 value of "foob" with a column 2 value of "ar"; both get joined into "foobar". The corresponding tuples would be different.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I had misinterpreted the original intent of the OP, and hence based my solution on that supposition. But, your comments are certainly valid. If I get time, I'll update it soon. Thanks for the feedback! :)